# Python seems to be slow solving Project Euler problem #21

Tags: python

I am trying to solve [Problem 21 from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21). I think that I've written everything correctly. However, I cannot get the final answer because the program does not get fully executed.

```py
def d(num):
    SUM = 0
    for i in range(1,num):
        if num % i == 0:
            SUM += i
    return SUM


SUM = 0
for a in range(1,10000):
    for b in range(1,10000):
        if a != b:
            if d(a) == b and d(b) == a:
                SUM += a+b

print(SUM)
```

Comment: What is problem 21? See [ask]

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=21

Comment: Perhaps the slowness is in your brute-force approach rather than Python per se. It shouldn't take 100 million steps to find the sum.

Comment: Actually, you are taking much more than 100 millions steps. What you are doing is calling an inefficient brute-force `d(n)` 100 million times. Your `d(n)` (for numbers in that range) is taking an average of 5000 steps, so you are trying to solve this problem using an algorithm that will take around 500 trillion steps. As a hint: 1) find a better way to compute `d(n)` and then 2) find a way to use it *without* using nested loops (perhaps by using a dictionary).

Comment: @JohnColeman I think removing the nested for loop will provide the biggest increase here since that will reduce the algorithm from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2)`. Improving the algorithm in `d(n)` on the other hand will only reduce the constant factor.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think that they should be able to get it down to `O(n*sqrt(n))`. Some sort of sieve-based approach could work.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yah, that makes sense. Still, your second suggestion will likely provide a larger performance boost than your first.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Definitely eliminated the nested loop would give the biggest speed-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for b in range(1, 10000)` loop is unnecessary, because you know that there is at most one appropriate `b`, and if it exists, it equals `d(a)`.

Also, beware of counting each `a` and `b` twice in your final `SUM`.

```
SUM = 0
for a in range(1,10000):
    b = d(a)
    if a != b and d(b) == a:
        SUM += a+b

print(SUM//2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me why did you divide SUM by 2?

Comment: Each amicable number would have been added to `SUM` twice, once as `a` and once as `b`.  Since the problem asks for the sum of all the numbers, each number should only be counted once.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the problem from the perspective of the divisors rather than the perspective of the number being divided. A key insight is that if `n < 10000` and `d` is a proper divisor of `n` then `n` must look like `n = i*j` where `i < 100` and `d` is one of `i` or `j`. Thus -- you should be able to determine all of the values of `d[n]`in the range by a nested loop, where the outer loop executes just 100 times. The idea is to create a dictionary of all candidate `n` (with values initialized to 0), loop over all candidate `i`, and then add `i` (and `j` if appropriate) to the value `d[n]`. The following works (and solves the problem for numbers other than 100000):

```
import math

def divisor_sums(k):
    s = math.ceil(math.sqrt(k))
    d = {n:1 for n in range(2,k)}
    d[1] = 0 #special case
    for i in range(2,s):
        for j in range(2,k//i):
            n = i*j
            d[n] += i
            if s <= j: d[n] += j
    return d

def amicables(k):
    d = divisor_sums(k)
    pairs = []
    for a in range(2,k):
        b = d[a]
        if a != b and b < k and a == d[b] : pairs.append((a,b))
    return pairs

def amicable_sum(k):
    pairs = amicables(k)
    return sum(a+b for a,b in pairs if a < b)
```

For example:

```
>>> amicable_sum(10000)
31626
>>> amicable_sum(100000)
852810
>>> amicable_sum(1000000)
25275024
```

The first one was instantaneous, the second one took less than a second, and the third one about 5 seconds (on my machine).

Comment: Does `d = {n:1 for n in range(2,k)}` starts a base dictionary adding divisor 1 to the sum? After that you only add the pairs of divisors, am i correct?

Comment: what an intelligent solution!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a python problem. Your algorithm will run slow no matter what language it is written in because you have three nested for loops when you can reduce it to only two. The problem is that you are calculating `d(x)` 100000000 times for each value of `x` in the range from 1 to 10000. You should only calculate it once for each `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be too much computation going on here. You have the second nested loop, with 10000*10000 execution, and each is calculating d twice, resulting in 10000 steps on average in the inner loop. This is 10^12 steps. I believe this will be slow even on quite potent machines. Can you think of a way to reduce the time complexity of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same technique as the sieve of Eratosthenes to build a list of factor sums.  Then match values at positions to find the amicable numbers.

```
# find amicable pairs (a,b) where a < b <= maxN
def findami(maxN):
    sumFact = [0]*(maxN+1)              # prepare factor sums list
    for n in range(1,maxN//2+1):        # propagate factors (up to half N)
        for f in range(2*n,maxN+1,n):   # add to multiples of n > 2n
            sumFact[f] += n
    return [(s,n) for n,s in enumerate(sumFact) if s<n and sumFact[s] == n]
```

Given that there is no amicable pair that crosses the 10,000 mark, you can use findami(10_000) directly to sum up the result.

```
print(findami(11_000),sep="\n")

(220, 284)
(1184, 1210)
(2620, 2924)
(5020, 5564)
(6232, 6368)
(10744, 10856)

print(sum(map(sum,findami(10_000))))  # takes 18 ms on my laptop

31626
```