# How should I enhance the working of my code for project euler problem 21?

Tags: python

I was working on the problem 21 of Project Euler and I have written the following code for the same:

```
def sumFac(x):

    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, x):

        if x%i == 0:
            sum += i
    return sum

def amicable(n, m):

    if sumFac(n) == m and sumFac(m) == n:
        return True

num = 0
ami = []

while num < 10000:

    if amicable(num, sumFac(num)) == True and num != sumFac(num):
        ami.append(num+sumFac(num))
    num += 1

final = []
for i in ami:
    if i not in final:
        final.append(i)

print(sum(final))
```

It takes 7 seconds to get the output but I guess it can be reduced to 1-2 seconds as this one is brute force method. Is there any other way this can be done? Also please suggest something so that inclusion of amicable pairs in the list twice can be avoided and no other list needs to be created to hold distinct values.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python seems to be slow solving Project Euler problem #21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639738/python-seems-to-be-slow-solving-project-euler-problem-21)

Comment: Be aware if you have working code and are looking for general improvements, this seems more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce it to run pretty quickly if you run the `sumFac` from `2-int(x ** 0.5) + 1` while inserting the `divisor` *and* `x/divisor`  (doing both work at the same time).

For example, if you run it with x being equal to 16, then we can check whether 2 divides 16 - if it does, we insert both 2 and 16/2=8. etc.. Thus we need to run until the square-root of the number.

**Note** that if lets say, we have the number `x=4` then we do not need to insert 2 twice, so you need to check whether the `divisor` and `x/divisor` are not equal.

This should be your `sumFac`

```
def sumFac(n):
    divs = [1]
    for div in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if n % div == 0:
            otherdiv = n // div
            if otherdiv != div:
                divs.append(div)
                divs.append(otherdiv)
            else:
                divs.append(div)
    return sum(divs)
```

Running time complexity of `O( n ** 0.5 )`

Answer (score 0):

There are two optimizations: the first being to only check for factors up to the square root and to add both `i` and `n // i` when you find a factor, and the second being to memoize the function to avoid repeated calculations:

```py
import math

def sum_factors(n, memo=None):
    if memo is not None and n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    total = 1
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            total += i + n // i
    if memo is not None:
        memo[n] = total
    return total

memo = {}
total = 0
for n in range(1, 10001):
    other = sum_factors(n, memo)
    if other != n and sum_factors(other, memo) == n:
        total += n

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer very quickly (in 1/100th of a second) using some inspiration from the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Build a list of the values of d(x) for all x from 0 to N-1.  Given that each factor `f` will be included in all its multiples, you can add `f` to `d[k*f]` for all positions that are > `f` because f doesn't contain itself (i.e k>=2).

```
from time import time
start = time()

N = 10000
d = [0]*N  # values of d[a]
for f in range(1,N//2):
    d[2*f::f] = (s+f for s in d[2*f::f]) # add f to all multiples of f 

# result is the sum of numbers a where d[a] meets the amicable condition  
result = sum( a for a,b in enumerate(d) 
              if a!=b and b in range(N) and d[b]==a )

print(time()-start) # 0.012 second
```

ouput:

```
print(result)       # 31626
    
for a,b in enumerate(d):
    if a!=b and b in range(N) and d[b]==a:
        print(a,b,d[b])
"""
220 284 220
284 220 284
1184 1210 1184
1210 1184 1210
2620 2924 2620
2924 2620 2924
5020 5564 5020
5564 5020 5564
6232 6368 6232
6368 6232 6368
"""
```